# Want to be able to check out encrypted MySQL data

Tags: mysql, encryption, phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin/MySQL, is it possible to encrypt a database/column/etc. and then display it onscreen unencrypted just for debugging purposes? In other words, can phpMyAdmin unencrypt data on the fly and display it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This would be very difficult to do seamlessly in phpMyAdmin - you'd have to modify the code itself.

As an alternative, you can add references to the AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT methods to encrypt/decrypt a column

Comment: No, no way I'm modifying phpMyAdmin in my lifetime. I'll make do some other way. Thanks for your answer!